# Select random string from given list

Tags: java, list, random, selection

I am trying to make Java select 1 random string from a given list.

Example of the list of strings:

```
1153    3494    9509    2   0   0   0   0
1153    3487    9509    2   0   0   0   0
1153    3491    9525    2   0   0   0   0
1153    3464    9513    2   0   0   0   0
```

Each row is 1 string

The idea is that it selects one, waits a certain period (like 7200 seconds) and replaces the previous string with another random string from the list (could be the same). 
The loop is sort of infinite.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Ps.
I am pretty much noobie with java :S, so i am afraid just saying i should use an arraylist (for example) wont work :P

Comment: Well, i tried to figure out arraylist, but i kinda failed in that..

Comment: Regardint to answers below - I think you should be more precise in your queston, maybe try to modify it. Write what situation you have: e.g. one thread or more threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> my_words = new LinkedList<String>();
    my_words.add("1153 3494 9509 2 0 0 0 0");
    my_words.add("1153 3487 9509 2 0 0 0 0");
    my_words.add("1153 3491 9525 2 0 0 0 0");
    my_words.add("1153 3464 9513 2 0 0 0 0");

    Random rand = new Random();
    while (true) {
        int choice = rand.nextInt(my_words.size());
        System.out.println("Choice = " + my_words.get(choice));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        int replaceTo = rand.nextInt(my_words.size());          
        System.out.println("Replace to = " + my_words.get(replaceTo));
        my_words.set(choice, my_words.get(replaceTo));          
    }
}
```

Comment: :D, the '1000' is the timer? But how is it defined when i want to use it somewhere else in my coding?  And is that one looping? (think i overlooked the loop though :P)

Comment: This is in milliseconds time when your program will be sleeping which mean will wait, you can change it to any value, even to constant and then you could use this in other part of your application. I'm not sure what do you mean "want to use it somewhere else"? - What do you want to use: time or this method?

Comment: but in your question is "selects one, waits a certain period (like 7200 seconds) and replaces the previous" - so first part of while-loop will choose string and second part will replace it. Everything will be save in your my_words list

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list/array of data and you want to select a random element from the list. The easiest would probably be to generate a random number with the Math.random (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) function which is between 0 and the count of your list/array.

You can then create a Thread that runs forever and sleeps for 7200 seconds between executions that generates a new random number and replaces the old variable.

Just watch out for concurrency issues when using Multi-Threading, have a read at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/.

**Update (Example):**

Java has a list that can be used to add, and remove data as you want. Data can then by extracted by giving the list the index (number) where the data is located in the list.

So you would be creating a list, then generating a random number in the list's range (0 to the size of the list as the max). And then extracting the data from the list by giving the list your random index. A example would be:

```
List<String> my_words = new LinkedList<String>();
my_words.add("1153 3494 9509 2 0 0 0 0");
my_words.add("1153 3487 9509 2 0 0 0 0");
my_words.add("1153 3491 9525 2 0 0 0 0");
my_words.add("1153 3464 9513 2 0 0 0 0");

//Maybe a loop to load all your strings here...

Random random = new Random(); //Create random class object
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(my_words.size()); //Generate a random number (index) with the size of the list being the maximum
System.out.println(my_words.get(randomNumber)); //Print out the random word
```

Hope this makes a bit more sense, and on second thought the Random class in java.util . Would be easier to rap your head around.

Comment: I don't really understand it... I give my strings a number or so? and make math.random chose a random number of this? The problem i have then is reverting the number math.random choses back to the original string. If you mean the string is generated by math.random.. The string itself cannot be generated by java. It should only pick one from a given list of strings

Comment: Btw, i included an example of the list on top now

Comment: Wow! Thanks! So if i implement that in my code, it would just select one of those strings? :O But, how can i make that replace the previous randomNumber every 7200 secs :S Btw, how is the randomNumber defined when i want to use it somewhere else in my code? just as 'my_words'?

Comment: How you would like go about changing the number every 7200 seconds is  up to you, you could create a separate thread, that does this in the background. See here for Threading Tutorial , http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial . Or you could create a loop in the main thread, but this will stop execution in the main thread.

Comment: Ah ok, and i just refer to the other thread in the main thread for that. Aha, Thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you're new to Java, this is a complete sample class to select random elements from a string list:

```
package com.jmcejuela.lab;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class SO {

    static final int SLEEP_TIME = 2 * 1000; //expressed in milliseconds

    static public void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();        
        list.add("hi");
        list.add("hello");
        list.add("booya!"); 

        Random rg = new Random();
        String randomElement;
        int listSize = list.size();
        /* No sense in randomizing when the list has 0 or 1 element
         * Indeed rg.nextInt(0) throws an Exception.
         * You should also check, maybe in a method, that the list
         * is not null before calling list.size()
         */
        if (listSize < 2)
            return;

        while(true) {
            randomElement = list.get(rg.nextInt(listSize));
            System.out.println(randomElement);
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        }
    }   
}
```

Then, what do you want eventually to accomplish? With a similar code you could set a class variable, for example. Most probably you want to have a separate Thread that runs this code.

Comment: Wow! thanks! :O, is that one also replacing its previous string? :O. Btw the timer is the 2 * 1000 ?

Oh and how is that one defined when i want to use it somewhere else in my code?

Comment: It is pretty hard to explain, but its for a gaming private server. The strings are coordinates where something spawns: the item spawns, disappears after 7200 seconds, and respawns at one of the coordinates in the list.

I could put this in a separate thread indeed :P

Comment: Yeah, that replaces the previous string. The input for Thread.sleep is expressed in milliseconds, so 2 * 1000 means 2 seconds. Write 7200 or whatever you want. For the rest you have to be more specific.

Comment: About the 'how is it defined' I mean, when i want to use this random number in another piece of code, what do i type for that. 'My_words' or 'random' or 'RandomElement'.

Comment: randomElement    You seem to be new to programming altogether. Why don't you start coding and experimenting yourself?